# azure container app does not update when updating it using cli

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-container-apps

I have an azure container app running an aspdotnet core 6 webapi. I try to update it using azure cli and get a successful response but the update actual does not happen. I even try to redeploy the container again using the cli but does not work. What could really be the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To update a container app, we use the `az containerapp update` cmdlet...

A new revision will be generated if your container app update contains [revision-scope changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions#revision-scope-changes).

These and other configuration variables and parameters can also be defined in a `YAML` file.

See [az containerapp revision copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp#az-containerapp-update) for complete information.

This below sample code updates the container image.

```
az containerapp update \  
--name <APPLICATION_NAME> \  
--resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> \  
--image <IMAGE_NAME>
```

The [Revision copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions-manage?tabs=bash#revision-copy) command can also be used to update your container app.

Please refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions) about Revisions in Azure Container Apps.